# Htaccess RewriteRule + 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a rewrite rule setup to map `/spaces/test.php` to `/areas/spaces/test/` as follows:

```
    RewriteRule ^areas/spaces/?$ spaces/$1.php
```

This is so the URL is mapped differently, but the underlying logic / code is still
  `spaces/test.php` .

So if we now access `areas/spaces/test/` or `spaces/test.php` they both work.
But.. I want a 301 to redirect `spaces/test.php` > `areas/spaces/test/` .

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rewrite rules to accomplish both things you desire.

```
RewriteRule ^spaces/([^/.]+).php$ /areas/spaces/$1/ [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^areas/spaces/?$ spaces/$1.php [L]
```

I'll walk you through the first line that I added:

- A request for `^spaces/([^/.]+)\.php$`
- Is rewritten to `/areas/spaces/$1/`
- But instead of an internal rewrite, use a redirect `R=301`
- `QSA` tells Apache to append any query string that was passed onto the new location as well.
- And `L` tells Apache to stop rewriting on that line when it matches, this way a redirect occurs and rewriting stops. On the next request for the proper location, the second line will match as you desire, so that internally it's the `.php` file handling the request.

See also: [official `mod_rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had a typo in my original RewriteRule and while I understand the logic behind this I'm still having trouble getting it to work as intended.

I have in there now (just as a single hardcoded location to test):

    RewriteRule  ^spaces/location.php$ /areas/spaces/location/ [QSA,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^areas/spaces/location/?$ /spaces/location.php [L]

Now, the redirect from spaces/location.php to /areas/spaces/location/ works just fine, but it still redirects again back to the original URL, causing an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^areas/spaces/([^/.]+)/$ spaces/$1.php [L,E=CLEAN_URL:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_CLEAN_URL} !1
RewriteRule ^spaces/([^/.]+).php$ areas/spaces/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

[Relevant SO question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67479/using-a-htaccess-to-rewriterule-and-redirect-301-at-the-same-time)